# What's the height of the UITabbar on iPad in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, interface-design, ipad

For both landscape and Portrait, if there's a difference.

Comment: Why not find a full res image and measure it to be sure?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the developer program and couldn't quickly find this... actually, couldn't find it in their onsite documentation, at all!

MIND BENDING!

For the rest of you, here's a non-apple site that has most of the dimensions for iOS 7 UI Elements.

http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/

Anyone know anything better? Please add it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [this source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html) is reliable and gives the answers to the question.

Screenshot from there -

[image]

No any info about Portrait/Landscape diffs...